# Facebook share thumbnail doesn't work

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, thumbnails, facebook-share

help needed! 
Here is a link to one section of my webpage, that I'm currently trying to make shareable on Facebook: http://fitboks.rs/vesti/fitnes/prilagod.html
As you can see, my page is completely HTML, CSS and JAVASCRIPT.
When I click on "SHARE" button, I don't see image or tittle that I've selected with META OG properties.
Can you look PAGE SRC and tell me where have I gone wrong?

P.S. When I run Sharing Debugger this is what I get:

- The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.
- The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
- The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog.
- The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Please help :)

Comment: [See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=http%3A%2F%2Ffitboks.rs%2Fvesti%2Ffitnes%2Fprilagod.html) indicates that the FB scraper gets presented different content. You need to go figure out why.

Comment: [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Ffitboks.rs%2Fvesti%2Ffitnes%2Fprilagod.html) shows you are using legacy character encoding `utf-16le` - might(!) have something to do with it, might not. But anyway, I'd follow the validator's suggestion and use UTF-8, anything else does not make much sense in today's web in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe You were right, I have to change encoding to UTF-8, and the problem is solved! Thank you!